# Bonita BPM could not execute statement

Tags: forms, persistence, bonita

I'm trying to run a process in Bonita BPM 7.3 but get the following error when I click "Start" in the generated Instantiation form:

USERNAME=elh1u | org.bonitasoft.engine.persistence.SRetryableException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

I tried changing the auto-generated form but it's not working either

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and how can it be solved ? Thank you

Comment: Hi, if possible can you share your process? That can help to understand what is going wrong. Also sharing Bonita BPM Engine log file (available from Studio help menu) and also exporting network log from web browser console (Save as HAR in Google Chrome) would provide helpful information to identify root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [lelh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4900888/ielh)

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`

PersistenceException Mean : you are try to overwrite persistanceid in some table

> For Resolve : delete your previous data from database (Studio > Preference > Database > Tick Clear > Restart Studio )

ConstraintViolationException Mean : Maybe in some contract or constraint in humantask form level configured and you didn't respect it.

> For Resolve : you need to send or respect it